# android gridview refresh

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView and I have a custom adapter for it to fill cells with custom data, some cells have data and other cells have lists. The lists are created dynamically and are populated using a custom list adapter.

I want to update or refresh everything inside the GridView after clicking on a list item, so in other words , the update/refresh needs to take place inside the GridView's adapter.

How should I do this ?

### EDIT #1

I use this code inside the adapter after I have clicked on an item in one of the lists inside of the GridView:

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After I click on a list item, the app crashes and I get this in the error log:

```
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at hnlapp.hairdresser.Adapter_Labels_GridView_Calendar_dayview.getView(Adapter_Labels_GridView_Calendar_dayview.java:428)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1222)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:268)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.GridView.fillSpecific(GridView.java:466)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1125)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1243)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1049)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09:37:58.675    916 hnlapp.hairdresser  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09:38:05.195    60  system_process  ERROR   InputDispatcher channel '406e82a8 hnlapp.hairdresser/hnlapp.hairdresser.Page_Login (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
09:38:05.195    60  system_process  ERROR   InputDispatcher channel '406e82a8 hnlapp.hairdresser/hnlapp.hairdresser.Page_Login (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

And that error message refers to this line of code inside my  getView method:

```
                Label = (TextView) convertView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `notifyDataSetChanged` method of your adapter.

Comment: ok , but I have to do this inside of the adapter, when I do this, I get an error.

Comment: @Janpan looks like problem in your implementation of `getView`. Can you provide whole code for this method?

Comment: ok , are you sure you want everything ? It's about 2000 lines of code because I declare a list in the view and have to instantiate all the list methods in the getview.

Comment: @Janpan wait a second, what kind of list? `java.util.List` ?

Comment: no , In the getView I create a list like this:

list = new ListView(mContext);

and then use a custom adapter to fill it:

list.setAdapter(new Adapter_ListView_GridView_Calendar(mContext, dagtyeVanhaarkappers.get(position-hairdresserids.size()), gebookdeurUser.get(position-hairdresserids.size()), tekening.get(position-hairdresserids.size())));

Comment: @Janpan ok. Can you load your code to some external resource and then provide link to it here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the textview as below:

> ```
> Label = (TextView) convertView.findViewByID(R.id.textview);
> ```

Comment: There is no need to set adapter again. `GirdView` will be notified as soon as you call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: Just remember that I need to call the code within the GridViews adapter. The code you suggest is from outside the context of the gridview adapter.